# Associative-array in Bash - problem with keys with dots

Tags: bash, shell, associative-array

I have a bash script which takes some names (eg development_3.4LTS) to an array, and then want to find its values (key=name, value=command) in associative array. It is running generally with no problem, but when I want to make operation on elements where key contains dots, bash goes crazy, eg:

```
COMMAND=($echo ${commands[development_3.4LTS]})
bash: development_3.4LTS: syntax error: invalid arithmetic operator (error token is ".4LTS")
```

Is there any way to make this running? I cannot rename keys, as this is company's way to name some branches on git..

Comment: Quote the keys? Run your script through https://shellcheck.net for more.

Comment: @Shawn I quoted keys, but received no effect - still fails on the same way

Comment: Did you declare `commands` as an associative array first?

Comment: @Shawn Yes, the way of it is: ```readarray -t lines < bisect-tools/job_commands.map

for line in "${lines[@]}"; do
    job_name=${line%%=*}
    command=${line#*=}
    commands[$job_name]=$command
done``` Where job_commands.map looks like eg. ```development_3.4LTS=somecommand --flag

Comment: You should edit your question to put your script in instead of trying to use a comment. And I don't see a `declare` there.

Comment: I figured what happened. What was wrong - lack of ```declare -A commands``` before loop. Now everything works fine, even if keys contain dots.